# iOS, transitioning between views

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

In the following code

```
- (IBAction)showAbout:(id)sender {
    AboutView *a = [[AboutView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutView" bundle:nil];

    [self setAboutView:a];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75]; 
    [[self aboutView] setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    [self presentModalViewController:[self aboutView] animated:YES];
}
```

These 2 lines appear to be doing absolutely nothing.

```
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75]; 
    [[self aboutView] setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
```

In this example, am i using them wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set duration of standard transitions.

Comment: can you provide an example of a non-standard transition?

Comment: @mac, well, you could use one of UIView's animation methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Answer (score 0):

As kovpas said, you can't set a duration for apple-developed transitions.  Delete the uiview part of the code and replace it with self.modaltransitionstyle= //your transition//.  And besides, without [uiview commitanimations] any animation you specify is useless by default.